# Proof Verification $ x \ge 0 \wedge x \neq 0 \Rightarrow x > 0$.

Tags: proof-verification, logic, constructive-mathematics

Let the real numbers and the relations =, >, $\ge$ be defined as in [this lecture PDF](http://www2.masfak.ni.ac.rs/cmfp2013/Nis%20lecture%20170113.pdf).

I want to show the following statement:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}( x \ge 0 \wedge x \neq 0 \Longrightarrow x > 0).$$

From $ x \ge 0$ we get that for all $(q,q') \in x$ and $(r,r') \in 0$ the following holds:
\begin{align*}
r \le q'.
\end{align*}
From we $ x \neq 0$ we get that there exists $(u,u') \in x $ and $(v,v') \in 0$ such that $[u,u'] \cap [v,v']$ have no rational point in common. $\underline{\text{This implies }  v' < u}$; whence $ 0 < x$.

I am not sure wether the underlined part is true.

Comment: If you give the link to the pdf, at least say were to look for the definitions

Comment: @Adam Unfortunately, the link does not have enumerated pages, but I would say that the definitions are slightly after the after the half of the paper. The chapter is called "the real line".

Comment: Every pdf does, look again. For anyone wondering, it's page 56

Comment: @Adam If you click on the link, you can't see that it doesn't. At least I can't see them. If you search for the chapter, you will immediately  find the definitions.

Comment: From $x \not = 0$ we have a rational interval $[a,b]$ containing $x$ and disjoint from $0$. If the interval is to the left of $0$, we have a contradiction with $x \geq 0$, from which we can obtain the conclusion. If the interval is to the right of $0$, then we see $x > 0$.

Comment: The definitions seem to start on p. 56 of the slides. Crucially, these slides write $x \not = 0$ for $x \# 0$ ($x$ and 0 are separated) rather than $\lnot (x = 0)$ (x is not equal to zero).

Comment: @Carl But isn't the step "interval to the left of 0 -> contradiction, hence to the right" using the law of excluded middle?

Comment: No, it uses the inference rule $\bot \to \phi$, which is constructively acceptable.  Another way of looking at it is that for rational $q$ we have $q < 0 \lor q = 0 \lor q > 0$, and so we can reason constructively about those three possibilities using excluded middle.   To put this in the language of your sketch, you know that $u' < v \lor v' < u$, and in either case you can prove $x > 0$. In the case $v' < u$ this is immediate, and in the case $u' < v$ it follows from the proof by contradiction rule, because it gives $\lnot (0 \leq x)$.

Comment: Maybe a better way of writing the inference rule for this case is: $[(A \lor B) \land \lnot A] \to B$. This is constructively justified as: if I know I have a proof of A or I know I have a proof of B, and I know I do not have a proof of A, then I know I have a proof of B.

Comment: @Carl Thanks. Maybe as a follow up question: Is it possible to show $ x \ge 0  \wedge \neg (x = 0) \Rightarrow x > 0$?.

Comment: isn't this what your question asks?

Comment: @Kenny No, there is a difference between $ x \neq 0$ and $ \neg ( x= 0)$.

Comment: Hmm, to me, the construction given has a striking resemblance to the construction via filters

Comment: @Diamir I doubt its possibility. $x > 0$ is an existence, $x \ge 0$ is a forall, $\neg(x=0)$ doesn't give you any data, so you're trying to construct something from nothing.

Comment: Doesn't that imply Markov's principle (P.55)?

Comment: @kenny I think you are right, it might even be equivalent to MP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have to justify *From $x \neq 0$ we get that there exists $(u,u′) \in x$ and $(v,v′) \in 0$ such that $[u,u′] \cap [v,v′]$ have no rational point in common.* as this is not an axiom used in your document for the construction of $\mathbb R$.

**Let's do it**.

By definition of $x \ge 0$, for all $(q,q^\prime) \in x$ you have $q^\prime \ge 0$, see page 59. This is also a consequence that the rational number $0$ is canonically identified as $\{(0,0)\}$, see page 57.

Now as $x \neq 0$, by page 58, you must have $(q,q^\prime) \cap \{0\} = \emptyset$. And this enables to conclude that $q > 0$ and therefore to $x >0$ using again page 58.

**The important topic is that for a rational number $q$, the "associated" real number is the set $\{(q,q)\}$ as stated in page 57. In that case the "associated real number" contains a single ordered pair!**